# Matlab: How to create a CDF array

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to Matlab and am trying to learn for school. I have created a vector of values with fixed differences between consecutive values. E.g. A = [1 2.5 4 5.5 7 8.5 10 ...].

I also have another vector of random values, e.g. B = [3 7 1 2 3 4 8 0 ...].

I want to create a new vector of the same size of A, which has numbers indicating the number of values in B which are less than or equal to each value in A.

In this example, C = [2 3 6 6 7 8 ...]

Thanks in advance!

Context: I am working on a CDF function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun()` to implement element-wise comparisons between arrays:

```
C = sum( bsxfun(@le, B', A) )
```

Here we're passing `bsxfun()` the "less than or equal to" function handle, `@le` . This produces a `length(B)` by `length(A)` logical array. We simply sum down the rows to get the total number of `TRUE`'s.

Comment: Perfect, this worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2562952 Great - glad to help!